# Google Drive's appdata size limitation

Tags: google-drive-api, appdata

I am wondering if the new appdata folder supports sub-folders. Is it just a folder with alias 'appdata' and hidden from users?

Also can files in appdata folder be shared with other users using the same application, like regular files in Google Drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no limit to App Data apart from the user's quota availability. If the user has 100Mb space, then you can create 100Mb of data in there.

You cannot share the App Data folder between users. This is a hard limitation that is unlikely to be restricted. If you have use-cases, please list them, as Google are always driven by community requests.

Comment: there are also a limit for number of files in App data ? if you know.